# How does one detect the name of main partition on Mac?

Tags: bash, macos, posix

I am writing a script to do an [unattended install](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch02.html#idm874) of VirualBox.  Given the name for the partition to which applications are installed isn't always "Macintosh HD", how do I detect the name of the main install partition for application installs?

Comment: Why do you need the partition name? Simply installing to `/Applications/` if able and `~/Applications` if not should be The Right Thing To Do™.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need it. The instructions in the VirtualBox manual are unnecessarily complex; you can always install a package to the root filesystem by specifying the target as `-target /`.

(In fact, the path under `/Volumes` representing the current root filesystem is always just a symlink to `/`.)